# Android Media Server died after some part played with Error 100 0

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have put file in in local storage `/data/data/<packagename>/files/abc.mp4`

and give path in `videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(localFilePath));`

and get error after some part of file played

```
 A/libc(4801): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x80000000 (code=1), thread 4801 (mediaserver)
 E/MediaPlayer(4071): error (100, 0)
 E/MediaPlayer(4071): Error (100,0)
 E/VideoPlayerActivity(4071): 0
 E/MediaPlayer(4071): stop called in state 0
 E/MediaPlayer(4071): error (-38, 0)
 E/ALSALib(4823): external/alsa-lib/src/control/cards.c:230:(snd_card_get_aml_card) cardname =AML-DUMMY-CODEC, card = 0
 E/ALSALib(4823): external/alsa-lib/src/control/cards.c:230:(snd_card_get_aml_card) cardname =AML-DUMMY-CODEC, card = 0
 E/AudioFlinger(4823): int android::load_audio_interface(char const*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.usb (No such file or directory)
 E/AudioService(3393): Media server died.
 E/AudioService(3393): Media server started.
```

Comment: can the abc.mp4 be played correctly on PC ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my MediaPlayer but it is working correctly after adding a reset  `mediaPlayer.reset();`